# How do I abort, pause and resume threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How do I abort, pause and resume threads in C#?

Related question:

[Is there a way to indefinitely pause a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-way-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread)

Comment: (see update to my answer re your comment)

Answer (score 23):

In general, **don't** pause (or abort) a `Thread` - you can't normally tell what it was doing, and this could lead to all sorts of locking issues, such as an a lock that isn't released, or a type initializer (static constructor) that is left hanging.

You might, however, pause code through more elegant methods - for example, using a `ManualResetEvent` in your loop that external code (on another thread) can open and close:

```
// worker loop
while(alive) {
    // if the gate is closed, wait up to 5 seconds; if still not
    // open, go back to the loop-start to re-check "alive"
    if (!gate.WaitOne(5000)) continue;

    // do work...
}
```

Then another thread with access (probably indirect) can pause (`Reset`) and resume (`Set`) the worker, but in the knowledge that it only pauses in a safe state.

---

Re your comment (on another reply) - it sounds like you have a reader and writer; ideal for a producer/consumer scenario. I have a an example [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211#530228) of how to write a producer/consumer with a capped size (so it won't swamp if the consumer runs slow) - the consumer blocks if there is no data, and the producer blocks if there is too much.

Comment: Hey, this is the second +1 I've had to give you today for stating one of my mantras: threads should be responsible for their own lifetimes, otherwise you get into all sorts of problems like deadlocks and lost data. After this one, no more soup for you today :-)

Comment: That's fine, I'm capped now ;-p

Comment: Im trying to get a collection of tasks to pause, allowing me to update a data table, before recommencing them all (They all read from the same datatable). Do you know of anyway i can know when the last task in the collection has reached the end of the datatable. Is ManualResetEvent the correct approach for my problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I did use `ManualResetEvent` to control the state of thread,but when I test this mechanism in VirtualBox hosted windows XP,it failed.

Answer (score 8):

If you've aborted the thread, it won't be able to run again. You could run the same task (e.g. the same `ThreadStart` delegate) on a different thread, but that's not running the same *thread* again.

I would *strongly* advise you not to hard-abort threads unless your app is coming down. Instead, work out a [graceful thread termination](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/shutdown.shtml) protocol instead, so you can tell a task that you want it to stop. The same goes for "pausing" a thread - you really don't want to suspend a thread while it's holding some critical resource.

Perhaps if you could tell us more about your situation, we could help more. Graceful pause/resume or cancel functionality is reasonably easy to achieve with [monitors](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml) (see the second half of the page) or [wait handles](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/waithandles.shtml).

Comment: I hereby propose a ban on both Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell... you are forbidden from answering complicated questions for the first 30 minutes and simple questions forever :P

Comment: my applicaion reading from rfid reader by contnuiasly thread and write tag's id data into database, at writing data on that tage i want to abort or pause that thread and resume it and how to pause specific thread
plz help me in that aspect

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pause a thread for a while, get it to call `Sleep`.

If you need it to pause until some condition becomes true, use a condition variable or a wait.

For condition variables in .NET use `Monitor` methods including `Wait` and `Pulse`; [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/WaitPulse.aspx) for an introduction. (Windows Vista also added native Condition Variable support to the Win32 API, but that is a completely separate implementation, .NET has had conditional variable support since V1.0).

For Waits: that is ant use of [`WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone) or [`WaitAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitany) method overloads of the [`WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.waithandle) class to wait on one of the various Win32 synchronisation object types exposed in .NET as subclasses of `WaitHandle` (events, mutexes, waitable timers and so forth).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it even though it's a bad idea, look at the Suspend and Resume methods - MSDN has [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x.aspx) on the subject, including why it's a bad idea.

To repeat - I strongly advise you to go with Marc Gravell's solution instead.

Comment: Dear newbie, here is a gun and while I'm at it you can have some dumdum bullets, be really careful never to use this stuff its really dangerous :P

Comment: Hey, I'm a big fan of Heinlein's "an armed society is a polite society" mantra, so yea, if after all these warnings he wants to go with Suspend/Resume... at least I answered his question :)