# C# Pause/Kill/Stop/Abort a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know there a lot of questions about this, but neither one of them worked with me.
So the problem is that I have a thread that is reading some MODBUS devices and I want to be able to start/stop the reading. When connect is chosen I start the thread and when disconnect is chosen I abort the thread. When I start the aborted thread I receive the following excepton:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Thread has already been started.
>       at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Thread:Thread_internal
>       (System.Threading.Thread,System.MulticastDelegate)
>       at System.Threading.Thread.Start () [0x00000] in :0 
>       at Vyshka.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00096] in /home/Vyshka/Main.cs:53

Comment: Once you abort a thread you can't start it again. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1054956/447356).

Comment: Do you have these statements in a try catch block?

Comment: Well how can I restart a thread ? Can I NULL-fy it and declare it again ?
P.S. The thread variable is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new thread. You cannot restart a thread.

Btw, you should (almost) never abort a thread. There's a lot of discussion about that on Stack Overflow which will explain why this makes your program inherently broken.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally never a good idea to abort threads, not to mention try to re-start an aborted one - once a thread is aborted there is no recovery from it so what your trying to do won't work. Instead spawn a new thread each time and let the old threads abort in isolation.

Alternatively, put login in your thread that controls reading to/from the `MODBUS` device so you don't need to abort the thread at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for the problem is to NULL-ify the variable and then assign it a new pointer.