# Windows Service: Restarting Thread/Task when running Notification method throws Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I am pretty new to C# and Windows Services but got my first service running to log data coming from a tcp client. At the moment I just start the Logging method during OnStart

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
         {
            MyDataLogger DataLogger = new MyDataLogger();
            MyDataLogger.StartLogging();
         }
```

StartLogging contains some Connections to Databases and a definition of a notification on the tcp client.
Up to now it works fine but I am concerned about undesired events like loosing the tcp connection. When undesired events occur I catch and log them in an error log but I am currently not able to restart the service properly. A colleague mentioned to start a separate Thread for the Logging procedure and restart it when an Exception is raised. So far I found different sources discussing several parts like [Windows Service to run constantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864673/windows-service-to-run-constantly) and [Restarting a thread in .NET (using C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054889/restarting-a-thread-in-net-using-c) of the needed solution. I also like the answer of [How to have a loop in a Windows service without using the Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032808/how-to-have-a-loop-in-a-windows-service-without-using-the-timer) but dont know how to implement it for my case with a notification in the Worker Function instead of a looped request.
At the moment I still have the following questions:

1. Which Worker is better suited for my purpose: a Thread or a LongRunning Task ?
2. How to check for the Workers status in OnStart without using a looped Worker function?
3. How to handle an exception from the MyDataLogger class to change the status and restart the Worker?
4. Is it correct to dispose all client/database connections during an exception and call the StartLogging again when restarting the Worker?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You want to avoid during anything lengthy in `OnStart`.  If you take too long Service Control Manager will report the service as _"not repsonding"_.  For this reason you should place the essence of your service in a child thread.  This thread represents the _main_ thread of the service.   Also, if your service does take a long time to start you should send heartbeats to SCM

Comment: LongRunning `Task.Run()` essentially creates a Background `Thread`. But my vote for `Task`.