# Resuming C# threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, resume, suspend

Possible duplicate question:  [Is there a way to indefinitely pause a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-way-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread)

---

In my code i do the below

```
Thread mainThread
//...
mainThread.Resume();

void StartThread()
{
    while (!wantQuit)
    {
        db.runEmail();
        mainThread.Suspend();
    }
}
```

Then i get the exception below because i call resume when it hasnt been suspended.

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException
```

I notice this warning

```
warning CS0618: 'System.Threading.Thread.Resume()' is obsolete: 'Thread.Resume has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'
```

So i wonder is there a way to resume and ignore the exception/case that it is not suspended? I hate writing the below instead of just one line

```
        try
        {
            mainThread.Resume();
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadStateException e)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy solution is to fix your logic and don't call Resume() when you are not Suspended().

But the Resume/Suspend API is indeed deprecated, take a look at, for example:

1) [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx), Wait() and  Pulse()

2) [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) or ManualResetEvent, Set() and WaitOne()

The static class Monitor is a little easier to use and integrates with `lock() {}` , but a ResetEvent might be more appropriate here because you can create it in set or unset mode and you are less likely to 'miss' a signal. By contrast, a Monitor.Pulse() will just be lost when the Wait() happens later.

---

Will inserted a link in your question, and while I don't consider it a duplicate, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-way-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread/143153#143153) there is well suited to cure you from using Suspend/Resume.

Answer (score 2):

WaitHandles are a better approach here.

Instead of suspending your thread, have it wait on a waithandle.  When you are ready to start up again, you "set" the handle from the other thread.

For a code example, see [MSDN's documentation of ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at using a Thread Monitor in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Thread.ThreadState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate%28VS.71%29.aspx) and check for [ThreadState.Suspended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate%28VS.71%29.aspx) before resuming.