# C#: Any way to pause the thread process that the resource used by that thread are released

Tags: .net, multithreading, process, resources

Can this solution work?
[Is there a way to indefinitely pause a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-way-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread)

Is the resources released with this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.  The only way to stop what a thread is doing and release any resources being used is to Abort it ([Thread.Abort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx)).

Comment: (I prefer to have the thread "terminate" itself. Then it can perform tear-down cleanly itself.)

Comment: Agreed- I was presupposing that this had to be an externally-imposed shutdown, and that the process running in the thread wasn't always checking whether it should be shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is *a lot* more to this question, just end the thread at an "indefinite" pause and create a new thread after the pause. When the thread isn't running just release all the restorable data/resources that make sense (from within the thread itself, if possible). Take time to come up with a *clear* life-cycle and resource-ownership model. In general, let the thread be "cooperative" and manage its own resource lifetime.

The general create/start/thaw/work/freeze/stop phases is the underlying basis of many long-running and/or pause-able jobs such as SharePoint Timers, Windows Workflow Tasks or SQL Server agents. Note that there is no "suspended indefinitely" phase in the list above -- this is just the space between the create and the start (or the stop and the next start) and is normally where external events enter the system.