# How to pause and resume a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#

This is how I did it in my code:
In the backgroundWorker DoWork event I did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _busy.WaitOne();
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label2.Text = "Website To Crawl: "; }));
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label4.Text = mainUrl; }));
                webCrawler(mainUrl, levelsToCrawl, e);


        }
```

Then in the pause button click event I did:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _busy.Reset();
        }
```

In the resume button click event I did:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _busy.Set();
        }
```

But it's not working when I click to start the process:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            this.Text = "Processing...";
            label6.Text = "Processing...";
            label6.Visible = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            checkBox1.Enabled = false;
            checkBox2.Enabled = false;
            numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Nothing happen only when I click the resume button the process start then when I click the pause button nothing happen.

I want that when I click the start process button it will start the backgroundWorker regular then when clicking the pause button it will pause and the resume button it will resume.

What did I do wrong ? Can someone fix my code ?

Comment: Opened question for editing...aaaand gave up :)

Comment: Just modify a boolean that the worker can access ? I would sove this IN the backgroundWorker, not by pausing the thread itself.

Comment: Aphelion please show me an example thanks.

Comment: what is `_busy` ?

Answer (score 11):

In your BackgroundWorker thread code, you need to find places that are safe to "pause" execution.  The ManualResetEvent is the right way to code.  This other post might help:
[Is there a way to indefinitely pause a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-way-to-indefinitely-pause-a-thread)

Basically, in a few choice points in your worker thread code where you want to allow it to pause, try inserting:

```
_busy.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
```

And when you want to pause (from your main thread) you use:

```
_busy.Reset();
```

And to resume:

```
_busy.Set();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple class that utilizes System.Thread.Monitor and lock()...

```
public class ThreadPauseState {
    private object _lock = new object();
    private bool _paused = false;

    public bool Paused {
        get { return _paused; }
        set {
            if(_paused != value) {
                if(value) {
                    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
                    _paused = true;
                } else {
                    _paused = false;
                    Monitor.Exit(_lock);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Wait() {
        lock(_lock) { }
    }
}
```

Using it is very simple...

```
private ThreadPauseState _state = new ThreadPauseState();

private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _state.Paused = true;
}

private void btnResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _state.Paused = false;
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    _state.Paused = false; // needed if you cancel while paused
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    for(var _ = 0; _ < 100; _++) {
        _state.Wait();
        if(worker.CancellationPending) return;
        Thread.Sleep(100); // or whatever your work is
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the `ManualResetEvent` like this ...

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    _busy.WaitOne();
    test(mainUrl, levelsToCrawl, e); 
}
```

... and then when you want to pause the thread call `_busy.Reset()` ... and when you want to restart it call `_busy.Set()`.

Additionally, you can place `_busy.WaitOne();` anywhere you want to pause.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the answer of this thread but I come up with my own solution i made and i just wanna share it with you. hope this works.

I have a background worker and i want to pause it when i hit close button of my form. asking "You are about to cancel the process" so it should pause the process.

declare `bool pauseWorker = false;` on your class.

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   while (condition)
   {
      if (pauseWorker == true)
      {
         while (pauseWorker == true)
         {
            if (pauseWorker == false) break;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         //continue process... your code here
      }
   }
}

private void frmCmsnDownload_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (bgWorker.IsBusy)
   {
      pauseWorker = true; //this will trigger the dowork event to loop that
                          //checks if pauseWorker is set to false
      DiaglogResult x = MessageBox.Show("You are about cancel the process", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
      if (x == DialogResult.Yes) bgWorker.CancelAsync();
      else 
      { 
         e.Cancel = true; 
         pauseWorker = false; //if the user click no
                              //the do work will continue the process
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Therefore the main solution here is the boolean declaration that controls the DoWork event of BGWorker.
Hope this solution helps your problem. Thank you.

Comment: This will eat up processor cycles as the thread will never suspend. Better to use a lock unless you know the pause is very short.

Comment: You're right. But its just very little process.And i cant find any solution thats why i create mine. besides i dont know how to use lock.

Comment: This is terrible lol. Don't do this. At least use lock() (bare minimum), Monitor (a little better), or ManualResetEvent (best).

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
bool work = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += myChangeFunction;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true && work)
    {
        // Your code here

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
private void myChangeFunction(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Here you can change label.text or whatever thing the interface needs to change.
}
private void Stop()
{
    work = false;
}
private void Start()
{
    work = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**NOTE:** If you want to change something of the interface, you have to put it in the myChangeFunction(), because in the DoWork() function will not work. Hope this helps.

Comment: This example isn't really a pause+resume type of example, which the OP is asking for.  In this case, it would make more sense to use the `BackgroundWorker`'s own `CancelAsync()` method and `CancellationPending` property instead of a separate `bool`.