# VB.net BackgroundWorker Pause/Resume

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I want to create two buttons that would pause and resume my backgroundworker but i don't know where do i start with my code, i have just started learning VB.net and wanted to learn about pause and resume function of backgroundworker.

Here is my existing BackgroundWorker code that i wish to pause and resume

```
Public resetevent As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim boo As Nullable(Of Boolean) = True

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        If BackgroundWorker2.IsBusy <> True Then
            BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()
            resetevent.Set()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Dim worker2 As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
    Try

        Dim Stream As New System.IO.FileStream("Sample.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Stream)
        Dim Index As Integer = 0


        Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
            resetevent.WaitOne()
            Thread.Sleep(500)
            eList.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
            Delay(1)
        Loop
        eArray = eList.ToArray
        Thread.Sleep(1000)

        Stream.Close()
        sReader.close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.ProgressChanged
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_Completed(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted
    Try
       resetevent.Reset()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub pause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pause.Click
    pause.Enabled = False
    resme.Enabled = True

    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        boo = False
        resetevent.Reset()
    End If



End Sub

Private Sub resme_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles resme.Click
    resme.Enabled = False
    pause.Enabled = True

    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        boo = True
        resetevent.Set()
    End If
```

This code is now working thanks for the tips

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause/Resume loop in Background worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359058/pause-resume-loop-in-background-worker)

Comment: my code is now working pause and resume works. thanks for the tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at

[Pause/Resume loop in Background worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359058/pause-resume-loop-in-background-worker)

and

[How to pause and resume a BackgroundWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780329/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-backgroundworker)

also

[How to implement Pause & Resume functionality with BackgroundWorker c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722232/how-to-implement-pause-resume-functionality-with-backgroundworker-c-sharp)

Use a converter for code that you need converted.. those should all have an answer for you.

Comment: i have now updated my code applying the things you have linked me but it is giving me an exception error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". It seems like the resetevent is not linked with my BackgroundWorker.

Comment: my code is now working pause and resume works. thanks for the tips. i have updated my code.